# Mi Formulario PHP no inserta la información en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, formularios, bug

Soy muy principiante en esto del código y estoy investigando por mi cuenta. Como primer trabajo quise hacer un formulario PHP Mysql pero no consigo que la información se guarde en mi base de datos. Sé que la conexión funciona, pero la consola no me dio más información sobre errores. Simplemente no guarda ni imprime mi función agregar_usuario.
Todo lo que puedan comentar, me sirve para seguir investigando.Les agradezco por adelantado.

```
<?php

require("connect.php");


if(!isset($_POST['nombre'])||!isset($_POST['password'])||!isset($_POST['email'])||!isset($_POST['curso'])){
  echo "Por favor complete todos los campos";
  die();

} else {

  $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conectar_db, $_POST['nombre']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conectar_db,$_POST['password']);
  $email = validar_email($_POST['email']);
  $curso = mysqli_real_escape_string($conectar_db,$_POST['curso']);

 function ingresar_usuario($conectar_db, $nombre, $password, $email, $curso){
  $sql_insert= "INSERT INTO tpractica(nombre, password, email, curso) VALUES ('$nombre', '$password' '$email', '$curso')";
  $data_entry = mysqli_query($conectar_db, $sql_insert);
  return $data_entry;
  if($data_entry){
    echo "Los datos fueron registrados";
    } else {
      die(mysqli_connect_errno());
      echo "Los datos no fueron registrados";
    }
  }
}

function validar_email(string $email){
  return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

ingresar_usuario($conectar_db, $nombre, $password, $email, $curso);
mysqli_close($conectar_db);
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenid@. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código en lugar de usar screenshots. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las normas de la comunidad.

Comment: La llave del `else` la estas cerrando después de la función y debe ser antes. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código para apoyarte mejor.

Comment: Entre $password e $email dentro del VALUES, falta la coma para separar

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, corregí la subida de código y chequeé sus sugerencias pero sigue sin andar. Agrego los cambios

Comment: Es mejor que uses sentencias preparadas. Usar concatenación, incluso con métodos de escape como `mysqli_real_escape_string`, podría potencialmente crear problemas de seguridad (p.e. dependiendo de la colación y los caracteres permitidos).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo que veo a simple vista es que cuando está llamando a la función ingresar_usuario() lo está haciendo fuera del else por lo que no tiene los datos de las variables $nombre, $password, $email y $ curso porque si analiza el código esas están definidas dentro del else.
Podría reorganizar el código poniendo la función arriba del todo, y dentro del else la llama.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Ahí lo cambié pero sigue sin insertar los datos. Sé que el error está en la función, porque todo imprime excepto eso, pero no estoy segura de qué sea.

Comment: ¿Probaste haciendo un var_dump dentro de la función o un echo de cada variable ($nombre, $password, $email, $curso) recibida para ver que es lo que recibe realmente?

Comment: La verdad yo no lo hago así con `mysqli_real_escape_string($conectar_db, $_POST['nombre']);` yo lo hago directamente asignando a la variable la entrada del metodo post, así: `$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];`

Comment: Bueno, esto lo hice porque, justamente, me corrigieron. Entendí que si asigno directamente la variable a la entrada sin validar, puede ser peligroso. Más allá de que éste es un formulario de prueba.

Comment: @WilmerPerdomo lo que sugieres en el último comentario es un problema de seguridad grave y no debería hacerse por ser una vulnerabilidad (inyección SQL).